# Не работает функция для выдачи роли при реакции

Tags: python, discord.py

Суть в чем. Человек пишет сообщение и только когда на сообщение поставят реакцию бот выдает роли этому человеку

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload): #отлов реакции на сообщение
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id) #отлов канала, где произошла реакция
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="test") #находим роль по имени на сервере
    await message.author.add_roles(role) #выдаём роль пользователю
```

Почему-то не работает

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема тут в том, что `message.author` может вернуть объект класса `User`, у которого нет метода `add_roles`, вместо объекта класса `Member`. Произойти это может из-за того, что сообщение, которое вы ловите, находится либо в приватном канале, либо человек, который его написал, вышел из сервера. Поэтому нужно обработать данную ситуацию и сделать так:

```
if isinstance(message.author, discord.Member):
    await message.author.add_roles(role)
```

Если же вернулся `User`, то тут уж ничего не поделаешь.